# What is a good PS3 and Xbox 360 emulator for Windows?

Tags: windows-10, emulator, xbox360, ps3

I am looking for a PS3 emulator for PC, as well as an Xbox 360 emulator. I currently have a first generation PS3 that is falling apart, and a first generation Xbox 360 that somehow still works...

I just got a used Dell XPS 8300 tower. 
It has an Intel i5 processor, clocked at 2.8 ghz with 3.6 on turbo, quad core.
16gb DDR3 RAM
1gb AMD DDR3 Graphics card. I put a 1tb Seagate HDD in it, and installed Windows 10 Pro.

I am looking at it mainly to replace the two gaming systems for my siblings and nephews, and any help in the matter would be greatly appreciated.

For PS3, my friend recommended  RPCS3, but he said that it suffers from a lot of bugs.

I am thoroughly overwhelmed by the sheer amount of 360 emus, so I was hoping someone knew a good one.

Thank you in advance for any and all pointers.

Comment: What does “good” mean exactly? If there are many different emulators, then perhaps they exists for many different reasons. While well intentioned, this question is really too subjective and a software recommendation at best.

Answer (score 1):

> I just got a used Dell XPS 8300 tower. It has an Intel i5 processor, clocked at 2.8 ghz with 3.6 on turbo, quad core. 16gb DDR3 RAM 1gb AMD DDR3 Graphics card.

The computer you're describing was released in 2011 -- it's quite old. It sounds like you may have upgraded its memory, but that's not going to help a lot in running emulators.

[RPCS3](https://rpcs3.net/) is the *only* PS3 emulator I'm aware of. Your computer does not meet [its recommended system requirements](https://rpcs3.net/quickstart), so it is unlikely to run at an acceptable speed. Even on a newer computer, [there are a lot of games which RPCS3 cannot run acceptably, or at all](https://rpcs3.net/compatibility); I would not consider it a viable replacement for a "real" PS3.

[Xenia](https://xenia.jp/) is the primary XBox 360 emulator I'm aware of. It requires a CPU that supports AVX; the processor in your computer is too old, so it will not run at all. Just as with RPCS3, [there are a lot of games which aren't emulated correctly](https://github.com/xenia-project/game-compatibility/issues), even on newer hardware.

TL;DR: This isn't going to work. Keep the consoles around.